# AngularJS routeprovider.config not called

Tags: angularjs, config, route-provider

I'm trying to build a simple AngularApp Here. I'm trying to add routeProvider and use config for the same. But the page never worked as expected. When I tried using fireBug in firefox, I found that the function present in the config, was never invoked. So, the code inside it remains untouched. (I was able to confirm that with breakpoints).

I believe that I'm missing something trivial here. Please help me figure it out.

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.8/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.9/angular-route.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/navbar.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/kscApp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-app="navbar">
        <nav-bar></nav-bar>
    </div>
    <div ng-app="kscapp">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#home"> Home </a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact"> Contact </a></li>
        </ul>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

kscapp.js

```
//Define an angular module for our app
var sampleApp = angular.module('kscapp',[]);

//Define Routing for app
//STACKOVERFLOW: The function is not getting invoked here. Please feel free to use firebug to verify the same.
sampleApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/home', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
    controller: 'HomeCtrl'
      }).
      when('/Contact', {
    templateUrl: 'templates/contact.html',
    controller: 'ContactCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/home'
      });
}]);


sampleApp.controller('HomeCtrl', function($scope) {

console.log('inside Hc');   
});


sampleApp.controller('ContactCtrl', function($scope) {

console.log('inside Cc');   

});
```

navbar.js

```
var navBarModule = angular.module('navbar', []);

navBarModule.directive('navBar', function() {
    return {
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'templates/navbar.html'
    };
});
```

EDIT: I had two ng-app in the source. I removed the navBar, and now things start to work fine. Can someone explain to me why this behaviour is seen? Both modules are independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

You don't inject the ng route module.It should be

```
var sampleApp = angular.module('kscapp',['ngRoute']);
```

Comment: You could look up your `console log` then post what you see.

Answer (score 0):

You are using different versions for Angular.min.js and Angular-route.min.js.
update your angular-route from **1.2.9** to **1.3.8**

Also inject 'ngRoute' to kscapp module.

Comment: Tried it, but still no improvement

Answer (score 0):

You can only use '**ng-app**' once in your application.

Concider moving your ng-app="kscapp" up to the html tag, and update kscapp to:

`var sampleApp = angular.module('kscapp',['ngRoute', 'navbar']);`

For more on ngApp, read [ngApp API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp).