# AngularJS routeprovider is not called

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, ng-view, route-provider

I've googled a lot of info about routing in AngularJS and have seen questions at stackoverflow, for example, [this 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15877925/angular-module-config-not-called), [this 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24984642/angular-routing-config-function-not-called), [this 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27665098/angularjs-routeprovider-config-not-called), [this 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21153616/angularjs-router-config-is-not-working). However, there is no result.

I've included `AngularJS 1.5.8.js` and `angular-route.js`.

**HTML:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="employeesApp">
    <head>
        <title>Injecting view</title>              
    </head>
    <body > 

        <p>Hey! View should be injected between these statements</p>
        <div ng-view></div>  
        <p>Hey! View should be injected between these statements</p>

        <script src="scripts/angular.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/angular-route.js"></script> 
        <script src="app/app.js"></script>
        <script src="app/controllers/employeesController.js"> </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**Employees.html:**

```
<h2>Employees</h2>
<article>This is employee view!:)</article
```

**employeesController.js:**

```
(function()
{
    var employeesController=function($scope, foo, bar) {//THIS CODE SNIPPET IS NOT CALLED 
                 alert('a1');
                 debugger;
                 $scope.sortBy='name';
                 $scope.reverse=false;

                 $scope.employees= [
  {joined:'2010-12-02', name:'Jon', city:'Reading', orderTotal:49.9956},  
  {joined:'1995-01-25', name:'Ben', city:'Las Vegas', orderTotal:519.99}, 
  {joined:'1994-06-15', name:'Joseph', city:'New York', orderTotal:344.99},
  {joined:'1998-03-18', name:'Adam', city:'Seattle', orderTotal:1021.5}
                 ];

                 $scope.doSort=function(propName){
                     $scope.sortBy = propName;
                     $scope.reverse=!$scope.reverse;
                 };
             };

    employeesController.$inject=['$scope'];
    angular.module('employeesApp',[]).controller('employeesController', 
                    employeesController);
}());
```

**app.js:**

```
(function() {   
    debugger;        //this code snippet works    
    var app=angular.module('employeesApp',['ngRoute']);  //this code snippet works  

    app.config(function($routeProvider){ //THIS CODE SNIPPET IS NOT CALLED
            alert('in');
            debugger;
            $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'app/views/employees.html', 
            controller: 'employeesController'
        })
        .otherwise( { redirectTo: '/' });                    
        });
}());
```

I double checked all directives and code, however `employee.html` is not injected.
Does anybody know what I am doing wrong? I am using `AngularJS 1.5.8.js`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only problem i see is you are redefining **employeesApp** in your controller

```
angular.module('employeesApp', []).controller('employeesController', employeesController);
```

Omit the [] part

```
    angular.module('employeesApp').controller('employeesController', employeesController);
```

You only define your modules once. Using `angular.module('modulename', arrayofdependencies or empty array)`

Everywhere else you just get the module and add parts, i.e. Controllers, directives etc,  using getter syntax. Do not use array here. `angular.module('modulename').controller`